# How can I get a Sin City/300 monotone and grayscale style

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, compositing-nodes, light

I don't know that I'm using monotone and grayscale in the right way, but I'm curious how to make a scene with has either only one tone like the use of Red in the movie 300, or something like sin city, where only one object is brightly contrasting.  Is this a compositing technique or nodes?  I know nothign about compositing and little about nodes, but i've been playing with them.  thanks for info, or sources to info for that matter.  Happy Blending!

Comment: Since you have absolute control over the colors in your scene, you don't have to create convert it to monotone and grayscale in post. You can simply use the proper colors for your materials from the get go. The tricky part will be getting the film Noir lighting right, then toning up the contrast in an artful way in post. I'd suggest you start from these two great resources: http://www.creativeshrimp.com/introduction-to-low-key-lighting-01.html
And: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorial-category/compositing-tutorials/

Comment: maybe this will help http://www.blenderhd.com/2015/stipple-paint-compositing-filter/